# Cannot find regex match C++

Tags: c++, regex, xml, string-matching

Im begginer in C++ and trying to find a regex match, but even that there is  < ID-Number>94893274123< /ID-Number> (without the spaces) in the xml file it doesn't find match. I am not quite sure if it is reading the xml file correctly...

```
 int main (){

 string line;
     ifstream infile("example.xml");
     if (infile.is_open()){
         ofstream outfile ("out.txt", ios_base::ate | ios_base::app); 
         if (outfile.is_open()){
             while (getline(infile, line)){
                 //ID
                 regex idnr (".*+<ID-Number>([0-9]+)<.*");
                 smatch id_match;
                 if (regex_match (line.cbegin(), line.cend(), id_match, idnr)){
                     cout << "Match found \n";
                 }
             }
         //closing all files
         outfile.close();
         infile.close();
         }
     else cout << "Unable to open output file\n";
     }
 else cout << "Unable to open input file\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Program runs returning 0 but that is all. What I am trying to do is to shred the xml file to pieces of information that I need, save it maybe into variables or vector later and reorganize them into another file.

Thanks for all the answers...

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and describe what is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Please post a few examples

Comment: Replace "it's not working" with 1) sample input, 2) a description of what you want the program to do, and 3) a description of what the program actually does.

Comment: I am sorry for earlier, posted it in quite a hurry... Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected (reports Match found) when compiling with Dev-C++ 5.11 (making sure you set code generation to comply with GNU C++11.  The only changes I made were to add the #include statements.

Make sure the file is in a directory where the executing code can find it.  Your ifstream constructor is a relative path.  The 'example.xml' file needs to be in the same directory as the one where the program is running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

 int main (){

     string line;
     ifstream infile("example.xml");
     if (infile.is_open()){
         ofstream outfile ("out.txt", ios_base::ate | ios_base::app); 
         if (outfile.is_open()){
             while (getline(infile, line)){
                 //ID
                 regex idnr (".*+<ID-Number>([0-9]+)<.*");
                 smatch id_match;
                 if (regex_match (line.cbegin(), line.cend(), id_match, idnr)){
                     cout << "Match found \n";
                 }
             }
         //closing all files
         outfile.close();
         infile.close();
         }
     else cout << "Unable to open output file\n";
     }
 else cout << "Unable to open input file\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Trying the same code using Visual Studio 2013 I get some errors.  First, go to DEBUG->Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging and make sure your Working Directory is pointing to the directory which contains the example.xml file you're parsing.  Next, look at the regex constructor

```
regex idnr(".*+<ID-Number>([0-9]+)<.*");
```

The period-asterisk-plus sequence is going to greedily consume any string and prevent the matching of the rest of the sequence.